# CRS for NOAA snow cover data

Tags: coordinate-system, noaa

I am helping an undergrad student with dissertation work.  The student wants to analyse this data:

https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/climate-data-records/snow-cover-extent

With CDO I created annual means then separated each into an individual file, then converted to GeoTIFF with GDAL.

The values are organised using the "NOAA NMC limited area fine mesh grid"

NASA Panoply can cope with the grid (i.e. plotting it on a map) but QGIS and ArcGIS Pro cannot (see attached screengrab). Ultimately the student wants to clip out a region and I can't see managing to do that if the ROI is not clearly identifiable and the CRS is unknown.

How can I create a bespoke CRS using the metadata (see below).

```
coordinates=latitude longitude
flag_meanings=no_snow snow_covered
flag_values={0,1}
grid_mapping=coord_system
long_name=NOAA/NCDC Climate Data Record of snow cover extent
missing_value=-9
NETCDF_DIM_time=19631.5
NETCDF_VARNAME=snow_cover_extent
standard_name=surface_snow_binary_mask
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.092329545454545
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.28949058791384
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
_FillValue=-9
More information    
coord_system#grid_mapping_name=latitude_longitude
coord_system#longitude_of_central_meridian=0
coord_system#semimajor_axis=6378137
coord_system#semiminor_axis=6356752.3
NC_GLOBAL#CDI=Climate Data Interface version 1.8.2 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
NC_GLOBAL#cdm_data_type=Grid
NC_GLOBAL#CDO=Climate Data Operators version 1.8.2 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
NC_GLOBAL#cdr_program=NOAA Climate Data Record Program for satellites
NC_GLOBAL#cdr_variable=snow_cover_extent
NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6
NC_GLOBAL#date_created=2022-01-04T22:24:20Z
NC_GLOBAL#frequency=year
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=90
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=0
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_units=degrees_north
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=180
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=-180
NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_units=degrees_east
NC_GLOBAL#institution=Global Snow Lab, Center for Environmental Prediction, Rutgers University
NC_GLOBAL#keywords=EARTH SCIENCE > CRYOSPHERE > SNOW/ICE > SNOW COVER, EARTH SCIENCE > TERRESTRIAL HYDROSPHERE > SNOW/ICE > SNOW COVER, EARTH SCIENCE > CLIMATE INDICATORS > CRYOSPHERIC INDICATORS > SNOW COVER
NC_GLOBAL#keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Earth Science Keywords, Version 8.0
NC_GLOBAL#license=No restrictions on access or use
NC_GLOBAL#Metadata_Conventions=CF-1.6, Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0, NOAA CDR v1.0, GDS v2.0
NC_GLOBAL#metadata_link=https://doi.org/10.7289/V5N014G9
NC_GLOBAL#naming_authority=gov.noaa.ncdc
NC_GLOBAL#platform=ESSA, NOAA POES, SMS, DMSP, GOES, TIROS, METEOSAT, GMS, TERRA, AQUA, METOP
NC_GLOBAL#product_version=v01r01
NC_GLOBAL#sensor=VIDEO CAMERA, VISSR, VAS, VHRR, AVHRR, VISSR-GMS, VISSR-METEOSAT, SEVIRI, MODIS, AMSU-B, AMSR-E, SSMIS, VIIRS
NC_GLOBAL#source=NOAA NH Weekly SCE, NIC NH IMS SCE
NC_GLOBAL#spatial_resolution=Minimum cell area 10676.8 km^2, maximum cell area 41804.6 km^2
NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=CF Standard Name Table (v22, 12 February 2013)
NC_GLOBAL#summary=The data record for the NH SCE CDR spans from October 4, 1966 to present. Prior to June 1999 the NH SCE CDR is based on satellite-derived maps of NH SCE produced weekly by trained NOAA meteorologists. Early NH SCE maps were based on a visual interpretation of photographic copies of shortwave imagery. Analysts incorporated various sources of imagery into the SCE mapping process as they became available (e.g. AVHRR, VAS). In June 1999 NOAA NH SCE maps were replaced by SCE output from the Interactive Multisensor Snow and Ice Mapping System (IMS) at the National Ice Center (NIC). SCE output from the NIC IMS is processed at Rutgers University and appended to the NH SCE CDR to form a cohesive, long-term climate record of SCE.
NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2022-01-03
NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=1966-10-04
NC_GLOBAL#title=Climate Data Record (CDR) of Northern Hemisphere (NH) Snow Cover Extent (SCE) (CDR Name: Snow_Cover_Extent_NH_IMS_Robinson)
NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,6}
NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=19631.5
snow_cover_extent#coordinates=latitude longitude
snow_cover_extent#flag_meanings=no_snow snow_covered
snow_cover_extent#flag_values={0,1}
snow_cover_extent#grid_mapping=coord_system
snow_cover_extent#long_name=NOAA/NCDC Climate Data Record of snow cover extent
snow_cover_extent#missing_value=-9
[![enter image description here][1]][1]snow_cover_extent#standard_name=surface_snow_binary_mask
snow_cover_extent#_FillValue=-9
time#axis=T
time#bounds=time_bnds
time#calendar=standard
time#long_name=time
time#standard_name=time
time#units=days since 1966-10-03
Dimensions  X: 88 Y: 88 Bands: 1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution as described in this poster:

ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/incoming/brodzik/posters/2015_agu_Haran_et_al.pdf

Tom Estilow from the Rutgers University Global Snow Lab says this:

"The projection_x_coordinate and projection_y_coordinate variables (in meters) are missing from the netCDF. While we are working on an update, I would be happy to send the coordinate files if you are interested in implementing the fix described in the poster."

Email snow_cover_extent_contacts@noaa.gov for the coordinate files.